# Why doesn't a function defined using exec() know about names in the locals dict passed to exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, closures, exec

When you define a function within another function and you refer within the inner function to local variables from the outer function, a reference to the variable from the outer function gets "captured". This is seen in the definition and invocation of the function f1() here:

```
>>> import copy
>>> def f1 ():
...     s = 'Hello'
...     def g ():
...         print(s)
...     return g
...
>>> f1()()
Hello
```

But if you use exec() to define the function, this doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> import copy
>>> def f2 ():
...     s = 'Hello'
...     exec_locals = copy.copy(locals())
...     exec('def g (): print(s)', globals(), exec_locals)
...     return exec_locals['g']
...
>>> f2()()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in g
NameError: name 's' is not defined
>>>
```

What is going wrong here? Why doesn't g() as defined within f2() know about the name s?

Note: copy.copy() is called on the dictionary returned by locals() because per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), "modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted". However, the same thing happens if you don't bother making the copy.